# Where should I store the API token to get it persistent throughout the AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, persistent-storage, bearer-token

I fetch the API tokens for the current user when he signs in.
This token needs to be persistent throughout the entire session.

I started by updating the default headers after the token was generated, but that update disappears when refreshing the page.

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer #{token}"
```

I tried to store it using *$cookieStore.put('API-TOKEN', token)*, but that didn't work as it was saved with the /user path. Making it only available from the /user scope.

Storing it in a Session fabricator also failed as that where emptied on every page refresh.
My next attempt will be to store it using sessionStorage. Perhaps with the help from http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage .

Which method is the preferred way?

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: You should'd store this token. Pass it in the URL for every request.

Comment: have the server persist the cookie in the header of the request response. It will automatically be included in subsequent requests until the cookie expires.

Comment: I need to sent the token with every http request. E.g.         `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer #{token}"` It seams a bit overkill to generate the token for each request. Should I not store it somewhere?

Comment: use `yourmodule.value('api_token', 'mytoken38u1239123e')` and inject it as a regular service in your controller. the variable `api_token` will be the direct value.

Comment: I'd recommend using an interceptor too.